# Determining the OS dynamically

Tags: java, operating-system, system-properties

I'm using the following piece of code for a Web Application

```
String OS=System.getProperty("os.name").toLowerCase();
if(OS.contains("win"))
{
    request.getRequestDispatcher("/result.jsp").forward(request, response); 
}

request.getRequestDispatcher("/result1.jsp").forward(request, response);
```

But when i run this application on windows OS it does not go to result.jsp.. It is going to result1.jsp

Am i using it in a right way?

Comment: What does `OS` contain prior to your `if` statement?

Comment: Are you sure that calling the `forward` the second time is ignored?  can you try adding the last line inside an `else { }` block?

Answer (score 0):

OS prefix for windows returned by `System.getProperty("os.name")` is `Windows` so modify the if statement to something like `if (OS.contains("Windows")` or `if (OS.startsWith("Windows")`. Also put last statement in `else` block.